# Limit Question: $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{3}{x}$. What does the "a" represent?

Tags: calculus

Just started doing limits today. Do not understand this question. Can someone explain?

Comment: To me it has no sens.

Comment: `3/x=??` . There is no equation we need to verify.

Comment: Thats the question.

Comment: I think that this is unclear. Perhaps a photograph of the question would be nice (photographs are not considered "good", but I think it would make this specific question much clearer).

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{3}{x}$ ?

Comment: Yes that is the question.

Comment: Intuitively the question is what value does $\frac{3}{x}$ get closer and closer to if $x$ gets closer and closer to $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here "$a$" represents a fixed number, like "1", "3", or "17". The answer actually depends on the value of this number. You have to consider two cases: (1) $a=0$ and (2) $a\not=0$. The answer will depend on the case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we are asked about $3/x$ while $x\to a$ so there are two cases. One case is indicated in @Surb's post and the other would be $a=0$. I think the problem wanted to remind something about vertical asymptotes. Indeed, when $3/x$ gets undefined (in means of $\infty$) while $x\to a,~~(a=0)$ then $x=a$ is defined as a vertical asymptote for $3/x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac3x=\frac3a$$unless $a=0$.

Comment: This not an answer to the question asked in my humple opinion. The OP does not asked for the value of the limit, but for the "role" of $a$ ...

Comment: I turned it to a hint.